# How to get the first/lowest value of an object with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following data:

```
{"20":{"id":20,"name":"Book 1"},
 "31":{"id":31,"name":"Book 2"},
 "1021":{"id":1021,"name":"Book 3"}
}
```

Is there a way that I could get the id of the first object or the object with the lowest id value, which in this case is 20 with javascript?

Comment: Objects are not ordered. So, there is no "first" value as such.

Comment: Get the keys of the object using `Object.keys`, and sort the returned array?

Comment: @thefourtheye sorry. If not the "first" then the lowest id value.

Comment: Do `key`s and `id`s always match?

Comment: @RickHitchcock yes they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the keys always match the `id`s, you can use `Math.min.apply` like this:

```js
var o= {"20":{"id":20,"name":"Book 1"},
        "31":{"id":31,"name":"Book 2"},
        "1021":{"id":1021,"name":"Book 3"}
       };

console.log(Math.min.apply(null, Object.keys(o)));  // 20
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the keys
2. Order the keys
3. Get the first key

Like this:

```
Object
  .keys(data)
  .sort(function (a, b) { 
      return parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10);
  })
  [0];
```

Comment: Since subtraction always casts operands as numbers, you don't need `parseInt`.  (Removing it will also ensure correct order if keys contain decimals.)

Comment: You need to sort by the id, not the key.